# Can I make a image validator like TextFormField when button click?

Tags: flutter, image, validation, video

I'm trying to make a upload page like this:

[image]

And I want the image / video have a validator like the TextFormField Error or give a toast that the image is empty and can't be uploaded

Comment: Please write some code her.

Comment: It's the File to check if null or not. What's the point of your question?

Comment: I wouldn't know if code is necessary, you can write it on your own but the main idea is to create a late bool variable. Let's call it "imageValidator". Once you click the "Upload" button if your File image (assuming you are using a File picker function) is null, then set imageValidator to false. If imageValidator has a false value, show a Text widget indicating that image can't be null. Otherwhise, if image is not null, set it to true and continue. The way I see it, using a late variable is useful to not show anything before user clicks "Upload".